# How to only return last api request (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

Alternating between the 2 buttons will display first names or last names, but pressing them together really fast will chain requests and will combine the two. How can I make create a check, and only display the names from the button that was pressed last

```
export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setName("first_name")}>1</button>
      <button onClick={() => setName("last_name")}>2</button>
      <Users name={name} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function Users({ name }) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsers([]);

    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=1`
    })
      .then((res) => {
        const allUsers = res.data.data.map((user) => <p>{user[name]}</p>);
        setUsers((prev) => [...prev, ...allUsers]);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }, [name]);

  return <div className="Users">{users}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great article by Dan Abramov about the `useEffect` hook in which he also talks about how to handle race cases- https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#speaking-of-race-conditions

To solve your issue, create a variable like `let didCancel = false` at the start of `useEffect`. Then, you have to return a function from `useEffect`, which automatically runs at the time when the name changes next time. In that function set `didCancel` to true. Now, you have to handle fetch response only if `didCancel` is false. This way, you are discarding all fetch responses received from second-last, third-last, etc. button presses, and handling fetch response only from the last button press.

Here is updated `useEffect` code:-

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;
    setUsers([]);

    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=1`
    })
      .then((res) => {
         if (!didCancel) {
            const allUsers = res.data.data.map((user) => <p>{user[name]}</p>);
            setUsers((prev) => [...prev, ...allUsers]);
         }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });

    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };

  }, [name]);

  return <div className="Users">{users}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a loading state, and the user should not be able to send a new request until the data is received... you can create a hook for this or use [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/):

let me give you an example:

```
function Users(usersList) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {usersList.map((user, key) => (
        <li key={key}>{user}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

const useFetchUsers = (name) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    fetch('https://blahblahblah.com/api/users')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response) => setData(response))
      .catch((err) => setError(err))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, [name]);

  return {
    isLoading,
    error,
    data,
  };
};

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('Tom');
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useFetchUsers(name);

  const handleSubmitName = (name) => {
    if (isLoading) alert('wait!');
    else setName(name);
  };

  if (error) return <>an error occured</>;
  if (data)
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => handleSubmitName('first_name')}>1</button>
        <button onClick={() => handleSubmitName('last_name')}>2</button>
        <Users name={name} />
      </>
    );
}
```

hint/note: it's just pseudocode and there are some tools to do data fetching + caching.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line `setUsers((prev) => [...prev, ...allUsers]);`. You are assuming that `prev` is [], but when the second request is resolve `prev` has data, that is why you see the request are combined:

I recommend to change your `useEffect` block to avoid the problem you are facing:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: `https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=1`
    })
      .then((res) => {
        const allUsers = res.data.data.map((user) => <p>{user[name]}</p>);
        setUsers(...allUsers); //--> with the last name's value 
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }, [name]);
```